# How does this zend controller and action work together?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I have some question about zend2's route.

This is a zend route and it is working, `www.mysite.com/api2/testme/49`

Could someone explain to me that when hitting `www.mysite.com/api2/testme/49`,
**how does the code flow to the controller?**

in

```
/module/Main/config/module.config.php
```

we have:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
      'Restful' => array(
        'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
        'options' => array(
          'route'       => '/myapi/:controller[/:id]',
          'constraints' => array(
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id'         => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
          ),
          'defaults' => array(
            'module' => 'Main',
          )
        ),
      ),
    )
)
```

`/api2/:controller[/:id]`, **why no action here?**

The controller:

```
/module/Main/src/Main/Controller/TestmeController.php
```

Content:

```
public function get($id) {
.... it reaches here.
}
```

Comment: This route does not appear to match the example URL you gave (`api2` vs `myapi`). Based on your controller function I'm guessing you have a rest route somewhere, and/or your controller extends `AbstractRestfulController`.

Comment: @TimFountain, it should be api2. Typo. Forget myapi